# How can I scale a single application in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: java, azure, cpu, load-balancing

I believe this could be applied to any application but in this case I am talking about a minecraft server (java). Occasionally the server will receive spikes mostly in CPU usage and I am wondering if it is possible to then share this load with another virtual machine. When I get times of high CPU load I would like to be able to boot up another VM in the same cloud service that will then share the CPU load. Is this possible to do? I know this is the idea behind availability sets and I understand how that would work in terms of a website etc, but not sure how this could be applied or if it can be applied to something like a game server where the application can only be run on the one machine at a time.

Comment: Just curious: why you choosed Azure to run Java applications when you have other options more "Java-friendly" like OpenShift? ( https://www.openshift.com/developers/java )

Comment: I have a MSDN subscription so I get free azure credit each month. Azure is also very java friendly so not sure what you mean...

Comment: @MarceloBezerra - I'm not sure why you chose to throw in subjective commentary here. Azure supports Java absolutely fine, whether in standard Linux distros, Oracle-specific distros, or Windows VMs. Plus there's a full Java SDK for the Azure API. This question is about scaling Minecraft within Azure.

Comment: pure curiosity (and i guess that i am about to find out that Azure can be a great option for hosting Java apps, because i will test it with java, i have tested it just for .net apps until now). You´re not supposing that i have some "obscure" interest around Azure, are you? =D

Answer (score 1):

If your app is running on a single server, the primary option is to scale *up* to a larger VM. While I'm not too familiar with how Minecraft manages its players: If all players need to reside on a single server (VM), there's really no option to CPU-share across VMs. You can currently scale up to 16-core, 112GB VMs with up to 16TB of attached storage.

Availability Sets are not going to impact scalability. They exist to allow you to have a set of VMs that are running in a High Availability (HA) mode, where they are spread across different *fault domains* (racks, network, power), and when host OS maintenance is performed, said maintenance would be staggered across VM instances in an Availability Set, avoiding all-at-once downtime.

Comment: So to use availability sets you must have the data duplicated (in case of website lets say) across all different VM's? But then how would these VM's even keep data synced up 24/7?

Comment: Why duplicate data? If it's all about, say, user session state, store that *outside* of the VM (in-memory cache, database, etc.). If you need common files, you can use an SMB share or many other techniques. Availability Sets have nothing to do with state-sharing or data-sharing. Imagine how you'd solve a problem with two or more physical servers. Same challenges apply. Availability Sets are about avoiding VMs going offline all at the same time.